# Hints on global deadman alerting methods

Tags: kapacitor

Kapacitor configuration file contains following comment in `[deadman]` section:

`# NOTE: for this to be of use you must also globally configure at least one alerting method.`

But there is no more hints about how to set this global alerting method. Some alert handlers sections have a `global` boolean parameter but not the basic or old-school ones like snmp, httppost or even log. Is it not available?

[Kapacitor documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/administration/configuration/) shortly introduces an `[Alert]` section. Would it be possible to set a global log event handler here?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding this means that in order to use the global configuration for the [deadman] node, you need to set the default parameters for one of the possible Kapacitor [Alert node] properties (smtp, mqtt, slack, ...)

The list of supported [Alert node] is available in the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/nodes/alert_node/)

This configuration is done in the **Kapacitor configuration file**.

Here is an example of the email property

```
[smtp]

  # Configure an SMTP email server
  # Will use TLS and authentication if possible
  # Only necessary for sending emails from alerts.
  enabled = true
  host = "smtp.host.com"
  port = 465
  username = "notify@host.com"
  password = "password"
  # From address for outgoing mail
  from = "notify@host.com"
  # List of default To addresses.
  to = ["dest1@host.com","dest2@host.com"]

  # Skip TLS certificate verify when connecting to SMTP server
  no-verify = false
  # Close idle connections after timeout
  idle-timeout = "30s"

  # If true the all alerts will be sent via Email
  # without explicitly marking them in the TICKscript.
  global = false
  # Only applies if global is true.
  # Sets all alerts in state-changes-only mode,
  # meaning alerts will only be sent if the alert state changes.
  state-changes-only = false
```

Comment: @Marbaf if this answers to your question could you consider to accept it ?